# What is the number of ways to express $\mathbb{Z_n}$, the ring of integers modulo $n$, as a direct sum of its ideals?

Tags: combinatorics, ring-theory

$\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a ring, ($\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}, \mod n$ addition and multiplication).  I think that the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are precisely the rings generated by its divisors.  For example, the set of all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are $\{\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}, \{0,2,4\}, \{0,3\}, \{0\}\}$.  My text says that a ring $R$ is the internal direct sum of ideals $I_1,I_2,...,I_n$ if: $R = I_1 + I_2 + ... + I_n$ and the intersection of $I_i$ with $I_1 + I_2 + \ldots + I_i-1, I_i+1, + \ldots + I_n$ is equal to $\{0\}$ for all $i$ in $\{1,2,...,n\}$.  So I think the answer to my question is the number of ways to partition (as a set) the distinct prime divisors of $n$.  In other words $B(\omega(n))$, where $B(n)$ is the Bell numbers and $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $n$.  I looked for this sequence on Sloane's OEIS but I was surprised that I did not find it.  I am very new to ring theory so I was looking for some confirmation (or otherwise) that my conjecture is correct.

Comment: how do you apply this to $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: Z_4 can only be expressed as a direct sum of its ideals trivially.  By trivially I mean there would be just one summand in the direct sum, Z_4 itself.

Comment: So isn't your question is just the following group theortical question? In how many ways you can write $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a direct sum of Hall subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: I do not know what a Hall subgroup is.  I will try to research it now.  Or if it is feasible can you tell me what a Hall subgroup is?  I have one semester of Abstract Algebra from which I was so confused I that I learned nothing.  Since then I have learned the basic theorems of group thoery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to see that this question is just the following:

In how many ways you can write $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a direct sum of Hall subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Then the result should be easy from the decomposition of abelian groups as direct sum of their Sylow subgroups.

Here a subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ is a Hall subgroup if 
$$(|H|,[G:H])=1.$$

Comment: OK.  Yes I see that the question is really a group theoretical question since every Ideal of a ring is a subgroup of the additive group. Right?  So to clarify by way of an example, 60 = 2^2*3*5, and the partitions of the set {4,3,5} (of which there are five)  correspond to the direct sum of Hall subgroups Z_4 X Z_3 X Z_5;    Z_4 X Z_15;    Z_3 X Z_20;   Z_5 X Z_12;   and Z_60.  Right?

Comment: In other words we are counting the number of ways to express the integer n as a product of its unitary (Hall) divisors,  that is,  divisors d of n such that gcd(n,n/d) =1.